# Python: Make SFTP connection using proxyhost and proxyport

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have trying to make a SFTP connection using a proxy
and print out the files in the SFTP directory

```
import pysftp

myHostname = "some.hostname.com"
myUsername = "test"
myPassword = "password"
myProxyHost = "10.10.10.10"
myProxyPort = "1010"
with pysftp.Connection(
    host=myHostname,
    username=myUsername,
    password=myPassword,
    proxy=myProxyHost,
    proxyport=myProxyPort,
) as sftp:
    print("Connection succesfully stablished ... ")

    # Switch to a remote directory
    sftp.cwd("/test/folder")
    directory_structure = sftp.listdir_attr()

    # Print data
    for attr in directory_structure:
        print(attr.filename, attr)
```

but I am getting a error of 'TypeError: **init**() got an unexpected keyword argument 'proxy''

could someone show me how to use proxy to make a successful connection.

Answer (score 0):

Based on [`pysftp.Connection()`](https://pysftp.readthedocs.io/en/release_0.2.9/pysftp.html#pysftp.Connection)'s documentation, it does not support `proxy` or `proxyport` parameters.

You may have better luck using the underlying [Paramiko `SFTPClient` class](http://docs.paramiko.org/en/2.4/api/sftp.html) – there's a [gist over here](https://gist.github.com/ovidiucs/e0aebf203f9280ead466) that seems to have an explanation about proxying with Paramiko.